# Possible to connect to Outlook WebMail via Java?

Tags: java, outlook, webmail

I want to create a java program to connect to an outlook webmail server to check for unread emails. I am not looking for an open source java based email client etc.. etc..

I am basically asking if it is possible to create a Java interface to an Outlook Webmail Server. I have been trying to hunt down how I would even begin to do this and it isn't inherently clear. Thanks..

Comment: Why not connect to the Exchange server the outlook webmail server connects to? You can connect to Exchange from java using POP3 or IMAP.

Answer (score 3):

You can use WebDav interface before exchange 2007 or EWS (Exchange Web Services)in Exchange 2007+

EWS Reference - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119.aspx

Also a blog that may start u off with webdav
http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/07/21/connecting-java-to-exchange-over-webdav-with-apache-httpclient.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to have a look at the free exchange clients. Maybe you'll find informations regarding the protocol there.

Comment: The protocol is defined explicitly by the WSDL in the EWS Reference, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119.aspx .

Answer (score 0):

Apache is developing a API for it Apache POI using which u easily can connect to outlook....